# Delete portion of string from variable including and after pattern with batch file

Tags: batch-file, search, replace

Is this possible?

For example, let's say I have a variable containing the following string:

```
str=This is a test - because it can be
```

What I need to do is be able to search for and delete everything including and after the "space, dash, space", from the %str% variable. So, I would end up with:

```
str=This is a test
```

I can easily perform this action on a single character, deleting or replacing said single character, but can't figure out how to do so with a pattern.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve the same result:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\08\07\SO_51729389.cmd
@Echo off & setlocal
:: you should always enclose the var=content in double quotes
Set "str=This is a test - because it can be"
Echo Original [%str%]

:: method 1 shuffle: string substitution with the asterisk
Set "str2=%str:* - =%"
Call Echo method 1 [%%str: - %str2%=%%]

:: method 2 change the " - " to a single char delims and use for /F
for /f "delims=|" %%A in ("%str: - =|%") do Echo method 2 [%%A]

:: method 3 similar to Squashman's
Set "str3=%str: - ="&Set "_=%"
Echo method 3 [%str3%]
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\08\07\SO_51729389.cmd
Original [This is a test - because it can be]
method 1 [This is a test]
method 2 [This is a test]
method 3 [This is a test]
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses string substitution to split the string by your space-space.  It reassigns the first part of the variable back to the str variable and the second part is disregarded by the use of nul redirection.

```
@echo off
set "str=This is a test - because it can be"
(set "str=%str: - =" & set /p "=%")<nul >nul
echo %str%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your issue can be done using **syntax-replacement**. I suggest you read more about it here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

For the sake of your issue, the format is set `SET _result=%_test:ab=%`. This will allow you to remove defined text fom the desired string.

**Code:**

```
@echo off

::Define text as string
set str=This is a test - because it can be

::Remove string
set str=%str: - because it can be=%

::Echo result
echo %str%

pause
```

**Result:**

```
This is a test
```

Comment: Yes, but what if the " - because it can be" string is completely random?

Comment: @user3208239 The process is the same. You can use syntax-replacement to extract the first part of the string and remove everything after it. Another way is to just completely remove everything after `This is a test`. Please take a look at the side provided.

Comment: @JohnKens, I think the OP made it pretty clear that they will not know what is before or after the ` - `.

Comment: @JohnKens: It is simpler this way: `::Define text as string` & `set str=This is a test - because it can be` & `::Get result` & `set str=This is a test`  **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini haha def is.